# Abbreviate the writing of several attributes at once with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, attr

I have some input tag with the attribute `class="item"`, and I would like to add a unique id attribute and attribute unique name. This is the code I used:

```js
$( ".item" ).attr( "id", function( index ) {
return "item" + (index+1);
}).attr( "name", function( index ) {
return "item" + (index+1);
}).attr( "value", function( index ) {
return "item" + (index+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="groupitem">
<input type="text" class="item"/>
<input type="text" class="item"/>
<input type="text" class="item"/>
</form>
```

I have no problem with the above code, but I just wanted to ask if there are other ways to prepare the writing jquery better or shorter than the code I wrote above?
Maybe someone can give an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do everything just in one action, maybe with `each` loop. It is even very easy to maintain and good to read imo.

```js
$(".item").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr({
        id    : "item" + (++i),
        name  : "item" + i,
        value : "item" + i,
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="groupitem">
  <input type="text" class="item"/>
  <input type="text" class="item"/>
  <input type="text" class="item"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what you said was true @eisbehr. It turned out this way more easily and effectively. I also do not need to add variable